# Simplewallet password confirmation during wallet creation

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, password-confirmation

I like to use very strong passwords, but occasionally make a typo when entering them. Is there a setting I can use so that simplewallet will force me to enter my desired password twice (and ensure they match) when creating a new wallet?

Comment: I would argue that this question can be closed (eventually) because the issue will be addressed by both the Monero GUI and whenever the new simplewallet is released (probably with the next update), so the question will loose any utility.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That feature does not yet exist, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/864) for it in GitHub and a [fix](https://github.com/guzzijones/bitmonero/commit/f0c0a3fb65c99b38dc63bb979baaee0d89bb0eaa) is being worked on.

```
+bool password_container::read_from_tty_double_check(const char *message) {
+    std::string pass1;
+    std::string pass2;
+    bool match=false;
+    bool doNotVerifyEntry=false;
+    do{
+        if (message)
+            std::cout << message <<": ";
+        if (!password_container::read_from_tty(pass1))
+            return false;
+        if (m_verify==true){//double check password; 
+            if (message)
+                std::cout << message << ": ";
+            if (!password_container::read_from_tty(pass2))
+                return false;
+            if(pass1!=pass2){ //new password entered did not match
+
+                std::cout << "Passwords do not match" << std::endl;
+                pass1="";
+                pass2="";
+                match=false;
+            }
+            else{//new password matches
+                match=true;
+            }
+        }
+        else
+            doNotVerifyEntry=true; //do not verify
+            //No need to verify password entered at this point in the code 
+            
+    }while(match==false && doNotVerifyEntry==false);
+
+    m_password=pass1;
+    return true;
+  }
```